# How to find if hyperthreading is enabled on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, cpu, hyperthreading

Is it possible to find out if hyperthreading is enabled within the BSD kernel of a given machine without watching the boot up sequence?

Comment: [This](http://www.directadmin.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-13418.html) may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be a way using sysctls to determine if a system has hyperthreading enabled or not.  `hw.ncpu` will just inform the kernel how many CPUs are available which will include cores, hyperthreads, and individual processors.

Also, the link from Prince John Wesley is from 2006 and no longer appear relevant.

As much as I hate grepping `dmesg`, you can do the following (on FreeBSD 8.x):

```
dmesg | grep SMT
```

Hyperthreaded systems should return a result.  Not hyperthreaded systems should not.

Answer (score -1):

You can determine this by looking at the output of sysctl `hw.ncpu`. If it is 1, you have no hyperthreading.

Comment: But if it's >1, it could mean multiple cores, not necessarily hyperthreading.

Comment: So 0 means HT is enabled?